# Determine if CGPoint is within image area

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to figure out whether a CGPoint lies within the shape of an image. The image is a simple black shape such as the two attached below. I'd like to create a method that determines whether or not a CGPoint lies within the black area of that shape.

I think this needs two things:
1) Turning the image into something that can be read with code (not sure what kind of image processing this would use or how)

2) Using that as a reference to determine whether or not a CGPoint lies within it.

Any help or ideas appreciated. I've never done image processing type of coding before. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You can create a `CGBitmapContext` backed by data that you control, in a format of your choosing. You can make it a 1x1 context, set the CTM such that the point you wish to test lies right at the origin, and draw your image into the context. Then test your data to see if you have a black pixel or a white pixel.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard: Why not provide that as an answer? Sounds like a solution.

Comment: @DarkDust: Because I didn't want to take the time to actually write out some code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at Ole Begemann's [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton). There you'll find an `UIImage` category that contains `ColorAtPixel` method. Guess that's what you're looking for.

You can then get `UIColor` of certain pixel with:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:yourCGImage];
CGPoint point = CGPointMake(pointx,pointy);
UIColor *pixelColor = [image colorAtPixel:point];
```

To simplify getting RGB values you could also take a look at [uicolor-utilities](https://github.com/ars/uicolor-utilities). Using `UIColor-Expanded` category you can simply determine let's say red and blue component. If they are low (pixel is dark) then tested point is inside shape.

```
CGFloat redComp = [pixelColor red];
CGFloat blueComp = [pixelColor blue];

BOOL isInsideShape = ((redComp < 0.5) && (blueComp < 0.5));
```