# Access a CGImage's origin?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to write a piece of code that can tell whether or not a CGPoint lies within an image's black area (successful answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554037/determine-if-cgpoint-is-within-image-area)). In my implementation, I can successfully  return an NSLog if the touch point is black with this code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
UIColor *pixelColor = [self.imageData colorAtPixel:point];
if(pixelColor){
    NSLog(@"hit a zone in the black!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"no hit!");
}
```

}

`self.imageData` is just a `UIImage imageWithCGImage` from `self.shapeImage.image.CGImage`. So this works perfectly, the problem is that the origin of my CGImage is incorrect. If I move my `self.shapeImage` to say (500, 500), my test only produces a hit as if the image was at (0,0). Its as if I need to somehow offset my CGImage origin to be properly aligned with the shapeImage.frame origin.

Any ideas on how to approach this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

it seems you make some confusion with CGImage:
CGImage have not origin property, just size.
it's just an image, it's not in a superview...
think of it as a jpeg or png file, they have size, then you use them in some UIView or other visual object that have a rect with an origin...

Answer (score 0):

Try testing at `point2` instead of `point`:

```
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake (point.x - shapeImageContainer.frame.origin.x,point.y - shapeImageContainer.frame.origin.y);
UIColor *pixelColor = [self.imageData colorAtPixel:point2];
```

Or defining point from `shapeImageContainer` *origin*:

```
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.shapeImageContainer];
```

EDIT: changed name `shapeImage` to `shapeImageContainer` so it would be obvious that we're talking about the object (`UIView` or something similiar) that's holding the image and not the image itself.